# ¿Por que no puedo poner una imagen de fondo en un JFrame en Java Swing?

Tags: java-swing, imagen, jframe, fondo

Estoy intentando colocar una imagen de fondo en mi JFrame en java desde la paleta que me ofrece NetBeans pero no me sale y me tira error, lo he intentado de varias maneras pero ninguna ha sido satisfactorio, o me sale esta excepción:

```
`"**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init> 
(ImageIcon.java:217)
at 
InterfazGrafica.InicioJuego.initComponents(InicioJuego.java:49)
at InterfazGrafica.InicioJuego.<init>(InicioJuego.java:22)
at myfarmMain.Ejecutable.main(Ejecutable.java:12)**"`
```

o me sale esto:
"**The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available**" y la imagen no sale en mi JFrame.
El primer error me sale cuando uso un JPanel encima del JFrame y le doy un absolute layout, luego con un JLabel le doy a sus propiedades y a icono y me cargo la imagen o tambien sin el panel y solo el JLabel entonces el JFrame con el absolute layout.
El segundo error sale cuando uso este método en la clase JPanel:

```
`public void paint(Graphics g){
ImageIcon imagen = new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Imagenes/Imagenes.jpg"));
        g.drawImage(imagen.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), 
getHeight(), this);
setOpaque(false);
super.paint(g);`
```

¿Cócomo lo soluciono? soy nuevo en esto :')

Comment: El segundo error es un error de dependencias de build (Maven o similares, no de ejecución). El primer error es que el *getResource* devuelve *null*, no encuentra la imagen